# PrimeFaces editor

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, primefaces

How to make the text aligned from right to left(p:editor) by default.

Currently using primefaces 3.0.M2-SNAPSHOT. Cannot update to newer version now?

This is required for Arabic version of application.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

add an entry in the web.xml like

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.DIR</param-name>
    <param-value>RTL</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and then by default any primefaces component will render the text from right to left

REF: http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2283

Comment: My requirement is only to components and not on entire scope.

Answer (score 2):

Not All PrimeFaces components have the attribute "dir" and since you're not using version 3.5, you cannot use the application scope DIR parameter. So basically, you have two choices:

- Apply a tricky CSS class dynamically to a component that does not have DIR attribute. Something like

  .rtlclass {
  float: right;
  /* etc */
  }

  or

dirClass property gets its values depending on the view locale. If Arabic, then the getter returns "rtlClass", otherwise "ltrCLass".

If by chance the PrimeFaces component has the DIR attribute, in a bean write something like :

```
public class FacesBean {

private String direction = "";

public FacesBean(){}

// Getter & setter

public String getDirection() {
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale()
                .getLanguage() == "ar") {
            direction = "RTL";
        } else {
            direction = "LTR";
        }
        return direction;
    }

}
```

and in your xhtml file:

```
<p:component dir="#{facesBean.direction}" ..... />
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this in a bad way, but it is working for me :

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:editor id="content"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
                myDiv.align = 'right';
                var myBr = document.createElement('br');
                myDiv.appendChild(myBr);
                jQuery('#form\\:content').find('iframe').contents().find('body').append(myDiv);
            });
        </script>
</h:form>
```